# how do i pass an option from a drop down into a data bean method in a foreach

Tags: jsp

Disclaimer: I am completely new to JSP, so I am looking for a simple solution to this problem.

I have some JSP which creates an HTML table. There is a header along the top, then the individual
rows are retrieved from a data bean and the HTML for each row created in a  loop.

Below is a brief snippet of the JSP.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="3">
<tr style="vertical-align:center;">
    <th>
        Event
    </th>
    <th>
        Scheduled
    </th>
    <th>
        Due Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Status&nbsp;
        <select name="statusFilter" onChange="location.reload()">
            <c:forEach var="filter" items="${dataBean.getStatusFilters()}">
                <option value="${filter}">${filter}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="event" items="${dataBean.getApsEvents(statusFilter.value)}" varStatus="status">
```

As you can see, a drop down has been added to the Status column, to filter the values that appear
in the rows below the header. The drop down does appear with the values as specified.

However, I have added a logging line to the getApsEvents(filter) method, to output the value being
sent to the method, and the value is always an empty string.

What changes do I need to make so that the user can select an option, and the option is passed
as an argument to the getApsEvents(filter) method on the bean, so that the loop only contains
the rows I am interested in.

The filter selected should be remembered if the user reloads the page, or changed if they select another option. But we do not need to remember it if they navigate away from the page, then come
back to the page at a later time, then it should default back to "All".

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to solve this I did the following.

i. On my data bean I added a statusFilter property, with getter and setter.

ii. I altered the JSP file to the following (select in a form):

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="3">
<tr style="vertical-align:center;">
    <th>
        Event
    </th>
    <th>
        Scheduled
    </th>
    <th>
        Due Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Status&nbsp;
        <form action="/thePage.html" method="POST">
            <select name="statusFilter">
                <c:forEach var="filter" items="${dataBean.getStatusFilters()}">
                    <option value="${filter}" <c:if test="${filter == dataBean.statusFilter}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${filter}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="event" items="${dataBean.apsEvents}" varStatus="status">
```

This added the drop down, and allowed me to resubmit the form, which set the parameter on the data bean. The standard getter on the data bean, used in the forEach loop, then filters the list returned accordingly.